# Java method overriding covariance inquiry

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, covariance

I have an inquiry about method overriding covariance ..
Let's say we have two classes as follows:

```
class Parent {
   Object getSomething(){
      return 10;
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   Integer getSomething() {
      return 10;
   }
}

class TestCovariance {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Child c = new Child();
      Parent p = new Child();

      Integer i1 = c.getSomething(); //this is ok
      Integer i2 = p.getSomething(); //this one gives a runtime exception
   }
}
```

As you see in the comment of that line that gives a runtime exception, exception details:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted
>   to java.lang.Integer

Why does it see the method of `c` object returns an `Integer` while the method of `p` object returns an `Object`??

Comment: Your Java environment -- presumably an IDE -- seems to be confusing you.  The program you present is not compilable in the first place, so although the `RuntimeException` is *about* your code, it is not emitted *by* your code.  Effectively, this is really a compilation error, not a runtime exception in the sense that we usually use that term.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you so much, you and Aomine made it clear for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to re-iterate that *covariant return types* is the ability to change the return type of the overriding method to a *subtype* of the overridden methods return type which in your case seems correct.

The call to `Integer i1 = c.getSomething();` compiles successfully because the receiver type is of `Child` and the compiler knows that the return type of `c.getSomething()` is `Integer`.

However on the other hand, due to the fact that you're using `Parent` as the receiver type of `p`, only the methods of the `Parent` class are visible through this reference even if the actual object `p` is referring to *is a* `Child` and obviously `p.getSomething()` is assumed to return `Object` at compile time and you're attempting to assign it to an `Integer`, hence the compilation error.

Having said that the call `Integer i2 = p.getSomething();`
*could* succeed at runtime but as mentioned it's a compile-time error as the compiler checks and ensures that you only invoke methods that exist for the receiver type.

Also as mentioned by davidxxx:

> the RuntimeException is thrown but it is not thrown by the program
>   itself but the IDE as it "discovers" that the started program has a
>   uncompilable class.

Comment: The JVM won't know the class instantiated until runtime. This analysis is incorrect.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy this answer doesn't say the contrary.

Comment: @Aominé Just one point : the `RuntimeException` is thrown but it is not thrown by the program itself but the IDE as it "discovers" that the started program has a uncompilable class.

Comment: @davidxxxI see... appreciated for the clarification. will reword my answer to hopefully make it less ambiguous.

Comment: This still doesn't describe the problem. It would not succeed at runtime, either. See my answer below. All Integers are Objects, but not all Objects are Integers.

Comment: Thank you @davidxxx

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy thank you too bro, I have replied to your answer

Answer (score 1):

As Aomine and John Bollinger stated, it's not a runtime exception, actually it's a compilation error ..

I have tried to compile those classes manually using javac command it refused to compile the third class `TestCovariance` saying that there is an error compiling this part of the `code Integer i2 = p.getSomething();`

The answer is stated in Aomine answer and John Bollinger comment

Answer (score -1):

- You are correct in that the problem has to do with the method signature. It has nothing to do with Parent-Child relationship, but that is contributing to your confusion.
- In this case the runtime exception is telling you exactly what is wrong. You can't implicitly convert an Object to an Integer. (Only the reverse is true).
- When you instantiated `p` as a `Child`, you assumed that your `getSomething` method would be overriding the one from `Parent`. It will not, because the method signatures are different. Overriding (not the same as overloading) can only be done when the method signatures (return type, number of arguments and their types) are identical.
- Therefore, the JVM is trying to call `getSomething` - inherited from the Parent - even though you assumed it would be from the Child since you instantiated it with that object type.
- You need to change your method signatures so both return an Integer, for example - simplest solution based upon my assumption of your intent.

Comment: No my friend, there is something called covarient overriding, and it says that you can override a method with changing it's return type, but the return type of the overridden method must be parent to the return type of the overriding method, the answer of @Aomine is true

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanAdel Thanks for taking the time to set me straight. :-)

Comment: No problem bro :)